# How to type a Button component that could return <a> or <button> and pass props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

Trying to build a  component that will return either an  or a  based on the prop "as". I also want to spread the props from  to whatever tag gets rendered to give flexibility.

**Problem**
I can't seem to get the types correct so that the element that is being returned doesn't give me an error. Here is my example (simplified):

```
interface ButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  as: "button";
}

interface AnchorProps extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  as: "link";
}

const Button = ({
  children,
  as,
  ...restProps
}: AnchorProps | ButtonProps) => {

  if (as === "link") return <a {...restProps}>{children}</a>;

  if (as === "button") return <button {...restProps}>{children}</button>;

};
```

It works fine if I remove the union type and use either AnchorProps or ButtonProps and then comment out the respective if/return statement. But as soon as I make it a union with `AnchorProps | ButtonProps` it gives me errors on the HTML  and  tags saying the types don't match.

I feel like I'm real close but can't quite get there.

Comment: add the "as AnchorProps" and "ButtonProps" inside the if condition ex:  {...restProps as AnchorProps}

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to Typescript to know that props are connected if you break the props apart, and *then* narrow one prop.

Instead, narrow the `props` object itself, then break it apart.

```
const Button = (props: (AnchorProps | ButtonProps)) => {
  if (props.as === "link") {
    const { as, ...restProps } = props
    return <a {...restProps}/>;
  }

  if (props.as === "button") {
    const { as, ...restProps } = props
    return <button {...restProps}/>;
  }

  return null
};
```

Also `children` can be spread with the `...restProps`. You don't need a special case to handle that unless you want to intercept it for some reason.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoC4AOxiSk3STgCEBXGGCagBRzADOcJAA861ACZDk6GADp2nbgAkAKgFkAMgEFOUYACMOSAQB41WxV2oBRADZIQSWgD44Abwpw4KAQC44ACIjJWpAgG4KAF8KKlp6RjRmbWo0AAtoPghBYTFnKURieRT06AsdPUNjM3KSjKh7R2cYN09yb18AwLsaAGsI6NjKcjRuAXgrbjgAXjgACjB+f3m6zKW4AB9WDmsswQBKfZnWrzhgTHnF7IE5Xxnp2e6+wKO2729R6nGPHwEAGjgciBRHGeyEURmcCuglO3iIMDYUGocFMKA8QLkIJgYKiAHoXJF2nAYsNvOdLktbkIHo8QtYXh5YXBPt93L8ARisWDiZDoQImfDEcjTHSpu5OSZsUs8QTTiTToKkXBqGw7HZouEgA)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best approach. You will get the best type support with the component since it determines what the `...rest` props should be based on the `as` prop you provide it.

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

type AnchorProps = React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>;
type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

enum ButtonComponentType {
    LINK = 'link',
    BUTTON = 'button',
}

type ButtonComponentProps<T extends ButtonComponentType> = {
    as: T;
    children: ReactNode;
    // based on the "as" value, either intersect with ButtonProps or AnchorProps
} & (T extends ButtonComponentType.BUTTON ? ButtonProps : AnchorProps);

export function Button<T extends ButtonComponentType>({ children, as, ...restProps }: ButtonComponentProps<T>) {
    if (as === ButtonComponentType.LINK) return <a {...(restProps as AnchorProps)}>{children}</a>;
    if (as === ButtonComponentType.BUTTON) return <button {...(restProps as ButtonProps)}>{children}</button>;
    return null;
}

// neither of these throw an error
function Test1() {
    return (
        // doesn't have "href" because the "as" prop is set to "button"
        <Button as={ButtonComponentType.BUTTON} type="submit">
            <p>test</p>
        </Button>
    );
}

function Test2() {
    return (
        // doesn't have button props
        <Button as={ButtonComponentType.LINK} href="http://google.com">
            <p>test</p>
        </Button>
    );
}
```